# WordPress Menu is is displaying vertically, not horizontally

Tags: wordpress, web

On my website, https://sciranch.net, My menu suddenly started displaying vertically instead of horizontally. [image]
Thank you. I am not sure what other information I can provide.

Comment: I understand this now.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After looking into your code, I found that `ul` tag has added `display:flex` property. you just need to disable that property for `ul` tag. See screenshot for reference:

[image]